# Partial flickering of HTML canvas while idle

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-canvas, flicker

I have HTML canvases on top of each other, I draw them just once, I witness that the load has been completed and everything is fine for few minutes, then randomly, without the canvas ever being redraw then lower half of the top canvas begings flickering, no JavaScript function being done in the background.

I have no idea what is happening here... Why would idle canvas change? This might be limited to Firefox 90.

[image: Recreation of the issue, both paintings are different canvas]

Comment: could be some form of z fighting? Consider adding a [mcve] to the question so we can run it ourselves?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I gave all canvases different z-index, and the flickering appears to be gone. Thanks!

Comment: @Chlodio Why not put that "changed z-index" info as an Answer. Might be useful to others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have disappeared after I defined a unique z-index for all canvases.